# AJAX post not being sent if triggered

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am trying to get AJAX post sent via trigger click event, click event is working but AJAX request not working.

```
$(this).find(".headermodelbtn"+text).trigger( "click" );

$(".headermodelbtn"+text).click(function() {
    alert(text);
    $.ajax({
        url: siteurl + "/audit/ajax/audit_setup.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { text: text, action: 'get_child_attribute' },
        success: function (data) {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
            $(".appendchildoptions").html(obj.list);
        }
    });
```

If I click on `"headermodelbtn"+text` manually it works.

Comment: Try to trigger the click **after** registering the click event

Comment: Did you check that you DOM elements (".headermodelbtn"+text) are completely loaded before trying to bind an eventhandler to it)? And what is exactly not working, the trigger event or the ajax post within the click event?

Comment: @tony_008 ajax not being post with trigger click, its drag and drop https://prnt.sc/q85oqg

Comment: Could you please provide here html code?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with:

```
$(".headermodelbtn"+text).trigger( "click" )
```

instead of:

```
$(this).find(".headermodelbtn"+text).trigger( "click" );
```

And make sure that you run that code **after** the click event has been already been bound.

**EDIT:**
Look at following console prints (***asume html dom element with id=buttonInput1 is the same dom element which has class=test*** ):

*printing with the devtools element $("#buttonInput1"), we have a single document context, (context: document) - look bellow:*

```
jQuery.fn.init {context: document, selector: "#buttonInput1"}
```

*and printing with the devtools element $(".test"), here we have a collection (note the '[input#button.....]') - look bellow:*

```
jQuery.fn.init [input#buttoninput1.test, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: ".test"]
```

So, they aren't the same. If you find by class you probably need to reduce more your set before registering the trigger. Please try with an unique id like:

$("#headermodelbtn1").trigger( "click" )

Comment: does the "alert" before the ajax work? when you call the trigger programatically

Comment: Can you try giving it a specific id to your button?  like this:  $("#headermodelbtn1").trigger( "click" ) . This is currently working for me in your same situation.